# IFrames load Asyncronously? If not why does this error occur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

**EDIT:** From tests it appears iframes do load asyncronously(though not fully sure). I fixed it by calling the function after a period of 700 milliseconds & that works. So it makes me think that they are asyncronous. I do this:

```
insertHTMLIntoIFrame( HTML ); //$("#updaterIframe").contentWindow.location.reload(true); 
setTimeout("convertToUpdatable()", 700);
```

**End Edit**

I have something weird occuring with my iframe in my webpage. My function searches my iframe for all HTML elements with the class "updatable" & converts those elements to textareas.

**My problem:** If I call the function right after I have inserted some HTML into an iframe then the function doesn't find any of the updatable elements(when they are there in the iframe)

**BUT**

If I delay the function execution by showing an alert(); prior to searching the iframe for updatable elements then I do find & convert all the elements in the iframe.

This makes me think that iframes load asyncronously, is that correct? If not what is going wrong? Is there a way to refresh the iframe or ensure I dont call my function until the whole iframe has loaded?

```
// I call the functions in the following order:
insertHTMLIntoIFrame( "blah");
convertToUpdatable();

function convertToUpdatable()
{
    // Post: Convert all HTML elements (with the class 'updatable') to textarea HTML elements
    //       and store their HTML element type in the class attribute
    // EG:   Before: <p class="updatable Paragraph1"/> Hello this is some text 1 </p>
    //       After : <p class='updatableElementTitle'>Paragraph1</p><textarea class="updatable Paragraph1 p"/> Hello this is some text 1 </textarea>

    if (STATE != 1 ) { return; }

    // if I dont have this line then I cant find any updatable elements in the iframe
    alert("Displaying website with updatable regions");

    $("#updaterIframe").contents().find(".updatable").each(function()
        {
            var className = this.className;
            var nodeName  = this.nodeName;
            var title     = getTitleName( this );
            $(this).replaceWith("<p class='updatableElementTitle'>"+title+"</p><textarea class='"+ className + " " + nodeName +"'>"+$(this).html() +"</textarea>");
        });

     STATE = 0; 
}

    function insertHTMLIntoIFrame( htmlSrc )
{
    try
    {
        var ifrm = document.getElementById("updaterIframe");
        ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
        ifrm.document.open();
        ifrm.document.write( htmlSrc );
        ifrm.document.close();
    }
    catch (ex) { alert("In insertHTMLIntoIFrame(): "+ex); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes iframe loading, and actually anything loading in your browser is asynchronous. Consider most anything that even smells like an event in js to be async and your life will become much easier.

Forget about setTimeouts, bind to events instead, in this case the `load` event on the iframe object.